# Facebook JavaScript SDK redirect URI don't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am trying to make a share button on my mobile webpage, same code works fine in a none mobile view, on a mobile device there is no way to open popup window so the only option is to open the link in the correct page so I managed to do that but after I click the share or the cancel button I get blank page and not getting redirected back to the mobile website.

Here is the code :

```
    <script>
FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxx", status: true, cookie: true});
  function share_me() {
    FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      app_id: 'xxxxxxx',
      display: 'touch',
      link: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=example.example',
      picture: 'PIC_URL',
      name: 'example',
      caption: 'example',
      description: 'Some description example text'
    },
    function(response){
      if(response && response.post_id) {
        window.top.location = "http://www.example.com";
      }
      else {
        window.top.location = "http://www.example.com";
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

I have tried bough methods sending with redirect_uri and redirect after response, they work well in none mobile view but on mobile I just get blank page.. any Idea ?

Comment: Getting same issue when trying in cordova inappbrowser, found any solution?

Comment: Not really same issue, but I got to this question from another issue - https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/318434747325688/ it may help someone